# Save Url of image to database and get image

Tags: php, laravel-5.8, image-upload, imageurl

- Hi I am New to Laravel I have done Upload a Image to path
  img/banner/{{image upload here}}
- My doubt is here is to save the image path in database with which
  user uploaded
- And while retrieving data how to give my URL path here.
- I have created a database name uploads

  id  user_id group_id    filename    extension   filesize    location    created_at  updated_at

  Blade File

  ```
  <div class="panel panel-primary">

    <div class="panel-heading"><h2>Slide Image Upload</h2></div>

    <div class="panel-body">



      @if ($message = Session::get('success'))

      <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">

          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>

              <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>

      </div>

      <img src="/img/banner/{{ Session::get('image') }}">

      @endif



      @if (count($errors) > 0)

          <div class="alert alert-danger">

              <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.

              <ul>

                  @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)

                      <li>{{ $error }}</li>

                  @endforeach

              </ul>

          </div>

      @endif



      <form action="{{ route('image.upload.post') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

          @csrf

          <div class="row">



              <div class="col-md-6">

                  <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control">

              </div>



              <div class="col-md-6">

                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>

              </div>



          </div>

      </form>



    </div>

  </div>
  ```

  Controller:

  ```
     public function imageUploadPost()

  {

      request()->validate([

          'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',

      ]);



      $imageName = time().'.'.request()->image->getClientOriginalExtension();



      request()->image->move(public_path('img/banner'), $imageName);



      return back()

          ->with('success','You have successfully upload image.')

          ->with('image',$imageName);

  }
  ```

  Routes:

  ```
  Route::post('/imageupload', 'Admin\ImageController@imageUploadPost')->name('image.upload.post');
  ```

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am expecting that you have included namespace, if not

```
use DB;

$full_path = public_path('img/banner');
$ext = request()->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$size = request()->image->getSize();
DB::table('uploads')->insert(
    ['group_id' => '1', user_id' => '1', 'filename' => $imageName,'filesize'=>$size ,'extension'=> $ext,'location' => $full_path,'created_at'=> date('Y-m-d H:m:s')]
);
```

You can get by this your database values, $imagename is the name you used to upload the image, not sure about your group_id so set to 1.

latest Edit

this is how you can get imageName:

```
$imageName = time().'.'.request()->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

froom your code only

Comment: Use of undefined constant created_at - assumed 'created_at'

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `uploads` (`group_id`, `filename`, `filesize`, `extension`, `location`, `created_at`) values (1, 1573642167.jpg, 38361, jpg, C:\xampp\htdocs\pwc_appli_chennai\public\img/banner, 2019-11-13 10:11:27))

Comment: Thanks as per your code when i upload image the location in database is like ***C:\xampp\htdocs\%%%%\public\img/banner*** and image wont upload in the img\banner path